# Keep element relative to another element using "position: absolute"

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, navbar

I'm trying to add a circle with an image inside to a navbar. The circle has to be bigger than the navbar such as this image:
[image]

I am using "position: absolute" so the circle remains at that position, problem is that on smaller screens it looks like this:
[image]

Covering the navbar items, how can I keep the circle as it is but make it's position relative to the rest of the navbar items?

I have tried removing the "position: absolute" attribute from the circle but that makes the navbar increase it's height to match the circle's height & align vertically the navbar items with the circle, as such:
[image]

Making the navbar too thick. If there's something I could do to maintain the navbar height and items alignment with it while leaving the circle centered horizontally with the rest of the items, that would be perfect.

HTML:

```
  <nav class="navbar p-4 z-2 justify-content-center">
    <div class="circle me-4">
      <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <a class="nav-item text-white text-decoration-none" href="#">MENU</a>
    <a class="nav-item text-white text-decoration-none" href="#">LOCATION & HOURS</a>
    <a class="nav-item text-white text-decoration-none" href="#">ABOUT US</a>
    <div id="socials" class="d-flex">
      <div class="sm-circle me-2">
        <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none">
          <img src="images/facebook_logo.png" alt="Facebook Logo" class="img-fluid">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="sm-circle me-2">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="images/instagram_logo.png" alt="Instagram Logo" class="img-fluid">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="sm-circle">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="images/tripadvisor_logo.png" alt="TripAdvisor Logo" class="img-fluid">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
    position: absolute !important; 
    top: 60px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #d58d26;
}

nav a {
    color: white;
}

nav a.nav-item:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 55px;
}

.circle {
    width: 155px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #d58d26;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.sm-circle {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.sm-circle img {
    width: 27px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: grid`, and `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows` to solve that problem.

In the grid, you have three items: the background, the logo, and the navigation.

- You divide your grid into three rows, and three columns.
- The logo will extend over all 3 rows, and is placed in the second column.
- The background will only be in the second row, and cover all three columns.
- The navigation will also only be in the second rows, and be places in the third column.

The `1fr` units in the row section ensure, that the remaining space the logo uses is distributed equally at the top and bottom, and the `auto` is just there so that the navigation bar can take as much space as it needs.

```css
:root {
   --logo-size: 150px;
}

.top-bar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [background-start] 50px [logo-start] auto [logo-end navbar-start] 1fr [navbar-end background-end];
  grid-template-rows: [logo-start] 1fr [navbar-start background-start] auto [navbar-end background-end] 1fr  [logo-end];
}

.background {
  grid-area: background;
  background-color: #d58d26;
}

.logo {
  grid-area: logo;
  width: var(--logo-size);
  height: var(--logo-size);
  border-radius: var(--logo-size);
  background-color: #d58d26;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 20px;
  grid-area: navbar;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-bar">

  <div class="background">
  </div>

  <div class="logo">
  </div>

  <nav class="navbar">
    <a href="#">MENU</a>
    <a href="#">LOCATION & HOURS</a>
    <a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```